# Generating an image of a database schema used in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, schema

How can I go about generating an image of a database schema used in a Rails app?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `rake db:schema:dump`?

Essentially, make sure that your `database.yml` file is referencing the database you wish to dump, and then run the command. It'll take all of the tables and indexes in said database and then write it out to `schema.rb`.

Note that you should rename `schema.rb` once it contains the dump; otherwise, it could it overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

try this ruby gem: https://voormedia.github.io/rails-erd

It will make a PDF, which you can also customize.