# How to generate database schema graph for one application using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, schema

I want to generate graphs to describe the relations within a application using ActiveRecord, is there some gem to accomplish that?

such as this one
[image: database graph]

Comment: please check this one..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481618/is-there-a-good-tool-to-generate-an-image-of-the-database-schema-used-in-a-rails

Answer (score 1):

There was good gem for this: https://github.com/amatsuda/erd

But as I see it was last updated 2 years ago.

According to the README it has the following features:

- Erd draws an ER diagram based on your app's database and models
- You can drag and arrange the positions of each model
- You can operate DB schema manipulations such as `add column`, `rename column`, `alter column`, `create model (as well as table)`, and `drop table`
- Then, Erd generates migration files on the server
- And you can run each migration on your browser

Comment: ERD works just fine, even though it has not been updated for 2 years.

Comment: ERD has been updated since - now supports up to Rails 5.